# Background not showing up using Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi I have this website in a test area.

http://newsite.carpetandvinylshowroom.co.uk/

Ok so on the homepage we have the latest projects that have a fancybox pop up. But there is no background showing

But if you go to

http://newsite.carpetandvinylshowroom.co.uk/services/quality-carpets

It is the same script same css there is nothing different at all but this page works fine. My code is pretty standard:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

Any help on this would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox does its overlay by adding a `div` to the page with ID `fancybox-overlay` and then styling that accordingly.  If you look on your carpet page (using Firebug/chrome dev tools etc), the `div` is being added.  If you look on your  home page, the `div` is also being added.  The difference between them is on your home page, the opacity is set to 0 (i.e. nothing).  On your carpet page, its set to 0.8.  If you change the opacity using Firebug, your home page looks as it should.

Question is what is changing the opacity of this element?  Try manually specifying the desired opacity in your call to `fancybox`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8)',
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If that doesn't help try having a look around your home page code for anything that may be effecting element's opacity and disabling them.

Comment: Thanks for that didster I just overwritten the style by doing:    opacity:0.8!important;

Answer (score 0):

i notice that in your homepage the opacity of the fancybox wrapper is 0 while in this page http://newsite.carpetandvinylshowroom.co.uk/services/quality-carpets the opacity is 0.8 if you want to overwrite the 0 opacity then you can put this in your main css to affect all your pages using fancybox.

```
#fancybox-overlay{ opacity:0.8 !important; }
```